# URL change but not request webview ios

Tags: ios, webview

everyone. 
I am building an hybric app that using web and Xcode. First time, I use a webview to open web app in which it contains a menu (on main screen). I use shouldStartLoadWithRequest to get request URL before it request. Then when user touch a button on that menu, I see that URL changes but shouldStartLoadWithRequest method not get called, I need to get URL in that method before it requests to know where it will navigate. Can anyone explain for me? I have no knowledge about web. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not figure out what is the problem but the following is my trick:
I detect that the URL changes but it does not request data. I use UITapGestureRecognize to detect when user taps to webview and perform an action after delay 0.01s to get URL. At this time, URL change to new URL of new page. After get URL I implement corresponding to that URL.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the function `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` gets called only for urls which is going to load content or, load new webview frame.

There are few kind of urls which might be assigned to javascript that doesn't actually load a page, may not work.  Do you need to intercept it before the link navigation occurs.

Also it would help provide better answers if you gave details of the action (`<a href="...">` or javascript) that the manu link will perform.

Comment: Webapp is code by php. But in android, I use shouldInterceptRequest to get url before webview request. It's OK on android.

Comment: I used a TapGesture to get url when user click on webview. I see url change when go to other page, but shouldStartLoadWithRequest does not get called. How to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: There have been a lot of questions about `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` and the fact that it does not always get called on all pages.  Unfortunately, I don't know of any solution that works 100% of the time.  Why are you trying to intercept the call - what are you trying to have the app do?  That may help me or others provide a working solution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As previous mention in question, I am building a hybrics app that use both webview and xcode. In webview, it has some buttons. When users touch that buttons on webview, app will navigate to our app. So I want to get the URLs before they request to detect where it will go and implement corresponding action on our app. Do you have any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the solution so others with a similar need can learn from it.  Thanks.

Comment: Please see above answer. Thank for your help.